# mpvolumeview on rotation doesn't take touch properly

Tags: ios, swift, uislider, mpvolumeview

I am using a mpvolumeview in vertical position in my app. But now I am not able to slide in slider properly. It only works at the bottom of slider.

My code for adding MPVolumeView:

```
volumeViewVertical = MPVolumeView(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: -80, width: 140, height: 140))
    volumeViewVertical.backgroundColor = .yellow
    volumeViewVertical.setVolumeThumbImage(UIImage(named: "vc_slider_circle"), for: .normal)
    volumeViewVertical.volumeSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.white
    volumeViewVertical.showsRouteButton = false
    volumeViewVertical.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    sliderLayoutViewVertical?.addSubview(volumeViewVertical)
```

Regards

Comment: I have a related problem: the slider doesn't want to move. Debugging in the view, it looks like the thumb doesn't have User Interaction Enabled, which is weird ... I'm going to continue to dig/Google.

Comment: Looks like it might be some sort of a bug - // https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/17462